# Install a specific package version in CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, installation, packages

I have two web servers, a production web server and a backup web server.

After running a `rpm -qa` on the two servers, I noticed some package discrepancies.

It seems like, someone ran a `yum update` at some point in the past on the production server, but did not run it on the backup web server.

I would like to install a few very specific packages on the backup web server.

for example : `yum install bind-libs-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5.x86_64`

If I run `yum install bind-libs-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5.x86_64` it seems to try and find the newest package that matches, and not the specific package I would like.

```
...
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 will be updated
---> Package bind-utils.x86_64 32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 will be an update
...
======================================================================================
 Package           Arch          Version                          Repository      Size
======================================================================================
Updating for dependencies:
 bind-libs         x86_64        32:9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6        updates        878 k
...
```

Is there a way to install only the package I would like and nothing newer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing you can do which can be a bit more work than previous answer but works as well is to download the package manually and then run

```
# yum localinstall /path/package.rpm
```

That should try to install the specific package you downloaded.

Comment: I was also thinking about manual install, but how would I get the rpm in question? I am not sure how to find a specific rpm with just the information i have.

Comment: Here you go: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/bind-libs-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5.x86_64.rpm

Comment: http://rpmfind.net/ is a useful resource for finding RPMs of various versions from various distributions.

Comment: True. I like to go straight to the distro though but yes, that site is really useful as well :)

Comment: I picked your answer because of your help with the mirror and the details about yum. I just appended .rpm to my corresponding packages and downloaded them all with wget (quick bash script). thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the following will do what you want, as by default yum won't let you install a release BELOW what's available:

> yum install yum-versionlock

and then:

> yum --allow-downgrade install bind-libs-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.5.x86_64

and to maintain this version in the case of future package updates to your system:

> yum versionlock bind-libs

Comment: You're welcome. Do let us know how it goes.