# Kubernetes requires Docker 18.09 but CentOS yum upgrades it to 19.03

Tags: centos, kubernetes

Kubernetes seem to require docker version `18.09` even if newer versions exist such as `19.03`...

When installing on `CentOS`, I made sure to pass the right version to yum.

Unfortunately, I did a `yum update` / `yum upgrade` after and it upgraded docker's version to the newest...

In Kubernetes documentation, it is specifically written to use 18.09, and I also get some warnings after issuing the `kubeadm init` command.

2 questions here...

- Why is still the newest K8s version not supporting `19.03`?
- How can I make sure CentOS doesn't update `18.09`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Alternatively, check out [versionlock](https://serverfault.com/questions/546100/install-a-specific-package-version-in-centos/546101#546101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You mentioned Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker) states that `18.09` is the newest version suggested.

> On each of your machines, install Docker. Version 18.06.2 is recommended, but 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 17.03 and 18.09 are known to work as well. Keep track of the latest verified Docker version in the Kubernetes release notes.

Although main recommendation is for Docker `18.06.2` because it is on the list of validated docker versions found in each kubernetes changelog since kubernetes version [`1.12`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#external-dependencies) to current newest stable version.

You can find lists of validated docker versions for each kubernetes changelog [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes).

**The currently newest docker version `19.03` has not been fully tested to be placed on list of validated docker versions.**

P.S.:

I have been working with Kubernetes, docker 19.03(current) was working fine and I had no issues on my test environments using Debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Note that on other distributions it might not.

Comment: Debian 10 uses docker 18.09, did you install 19.03 from upstream yourself ? (I know this message was written a year ago, but maybe you remember)